# Dynamic Content without PHP or a licensed CMS

Tags: content-management-system

I'm building a design library for our internal team. I can code it all by hand, and even introduce some client-side includes to handle stuff like navigation menus, but at some point it will be easier, I assume, to be able to serve up some of the content dynamically.

I don't want to implement Drupal or anything similar, because I just don't want to (a) introduce the nightmare of administration that brings, and (b) have to fit within their definition/structure of how to build what I want to build.

Here are some examples of what I want to do...have an array somewhere that lists a set of widgets, and present that array on a page. Clicking on one of them would take you to a library page about that widget. The individual pages can easily be hand-written--I just want to take some of the lists and data that need to appear on multiple pages (but always be the same), and present that content.

The other element of what I want is collaboration--allowing folks to add comments on a page.

So I'd love to hear whether I just need to suck it up and use a CMS or if this is a doable thing.

Answer (score 0):

So far, the answer has been javascript and json files, although I'm also considering using something like mustache.